# JsonArray output is not working

Tags: java, json, api, jersey, jackson

Im pretty new with json so I dont understand what i`m doing wrong..
I want my data json output like this, but i`m not getting it good.

```
{ "data": [
    ["2014-01", 71173],
    ["2014-02", 57624],
    ["2014-03", 64851],
    ["2014-04", 60486],
    ["2014-05", 60500],
    ["2014-06", 62908],
    ["2014-07", 64818],
    ["2014-08", 59961],
    ["2014-09", 58542],
    ["2014-10", 22050]
  ]  }
```

This is what I get:

```
{ "data": [
"hallo 0",
"hallo 10",
"hallo 20",
"hallo 30",
"hallo 40",
"hallo 50",
"hallo 60",
"hallo 70",
"hallo 80",
"hallo 90" ] }
```

This is the class for data with the name TestTest

```
public class TestTest {

    @JsonProperty("data")
    private List<List<Object>> data = new ArrayList<List<Object>>();

    public TestTest(){

    }

    @JsonProperty("data")
    public List<List<Object>> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    @JsonProperty("data")
    public void setData(List<List<Object>> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}


    @GET
    @Path("/CallsPerMinuteAsLineChart")
    public Response getTest(){
        TestTest test = new TestTest();
        List<List<Object>> data = new ArrayList<List<Object>>();

        int loop;

        for(loop=0; loop < 100; loop = loop + 10){
            List<Object> dataitem = new ArrayList<>();
            dataitem.add("hallo");
            dataitem.add(loop);
            data.add(dataitem);
        }

        test.setData(data);
        return Response.ok(test).build();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is not about your json structure, although it's not a good practice to create a nested list like that, I tried your code with `Gson` and `Jackson`

```
        TestTest test = new TestTest();
        List<List<Object>> data = new ArrayList<List<Object>>();

        int loop;

        for( loop = 0; loop < 100; loop = loop + 10 ){
            List<Object> dataitem = new ArrayList<>();
            dataitem.add( "hallo" );
            dataitem.add( loop );
            data.add( dataitem );
        }

        test.setData( data );

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String jackson = mapper.writeValueAsString( test );

        System.out.println( new Gson().toJson( test ) );
        System.out.println( jackson );
```

This code prints:

```
{"data":[["hallo",0],["hallo",10],["hallo",20],["hallo",30],["hallo",40],["hallo",50],["hallo",60],["hallo",70],["hallo",80],["hallo",90]]}
{"data":[["hallo",0],["hallo",10],["hallo",20],["hallo",30],["hallo",40],["hallo",50],["hallo",60],["hallo",70],["hallo",80],["hallo",90]]}
```

Which is exactly what you want. Since nobody explicitly solve your problem without knowing all the details I suggest you to use it like that:

```
@GET
@Path("/CallsPerMinuteAsLineChart")
public String getTest(){
```

And in this method just return the json string as I converted them.

Answer (score 0):

```
 List<Object> dataitem = new ArrayList<>();
        dataitem.add( "hallo" );
        dataitem.add( loop );
        data.add( dataitem );
```

in code above you are adding a single object (dataitem) in loop and that is what you see in output. I Suggest, instead on list either use a object(Strung key, string val) type or a map ( k,v) - Possible options

```
1. User Map
      Map<String, Object> dataitem = new HashMap<String, Object>();
Iterate the map and print object properties.
2. List of Object - where Object can have id and value as attribute that you print.
      List<Object> dataitem = new ArrayList<Object>();
or Simply 
 3. Map<String, String> dataitem = new HashMap<String, String>();
Pring k.V for map
```

Answer (score 0):

A nice way to solve this problem is by creating serializable objects, e.g.

```
public class Item {

    private String label;
    private int value;

    public Item() {

    }

    public Item(String label, int number) {
        this.label = label;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public int getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
}

public class Data {

    private List<Item> items;

    public Data() {
        items = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void addItem(Item item) {
        items.add(item);
    }
}
```

Your method:

```
@GET
@Path("/callsperminuteaslinechart")
public Response getTest(){
    Data data = new Data();

    for (int i = 10; i <= 100; i += 10) {
        data.addItem(new Item("Hello", i));
    }

    return Response.ok(data).build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sharing what I did, which I think is inline with what others have shared before me.

```
package general;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONObject;

public class GenerateJSONout {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<List<Object>> data = new ArrayList<List<Object>>();

    int loop;

    for( loop = 0; loop < 100; loop = loop + 10 ){
        List<Object> dataitem = new ArrayList<>();
        dataitem.add( "hallo" );
        dataitem.add( loop );
        data.add( dataitem );
    }


    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();       
    jo.put("data", data);

    System.out.println(jo.toString());
}
```

}
Result:

```
{"data":[["hallo",0],["hallo",10],["hallo",20],["hallo",30],["hallo",40],["hallo",50],["hallo",60],["hallo",70],["hallo",80],["hallo",90]]}
```

Comment: This is not the answer what this person is asking for.